# Get Audiofile Metainformation (Title/Genre) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, file, audio, title, meta

I want to get the title and the genre of an audiofile (by path) with javascript to display it on my web music player. Is this possible?

I looked for that a long time now and didn't find anything that could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metainformation of **MP3 files** is stored in [ID3](http://id3.org/) containers. You can use [JavaScript-ID3-Reader](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader) or similar library to decode it.

```html
<script src="id3-minimized.js"></script>
<script>
ID3.loadTags("filename.mp3", function() {
    var tags = ID3.getAllTags("filename.mp3");
    console.log(tags);
});
</script>
```

Sample output

```
{"version":"1.1","title":"Allegro from Duet in C Major","artist":"","album":"","year":"","comment":"","track":0,"genre":""}
```